# Attaching event-listeners to wrapping components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have a problem understanding the mechanics of attaching events in React.
Below is an illustration.

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Wrapper onClick={() => {console.log('outer wrapper click')}}>
                <button>click me</button>
            </Wrapper>
        </div>
    );
}

function Wrapper (props) {
    return (
        <div onClick={() => {console.log('inner wrapper click')}}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want to attach an event handler on the Wrapper component, but as it stands right now, only the 'inner wrapper click' will be logged. Is it possible to make ('outer wrapper click') work somehow?

Why is that and how does it work?
What happened with the 'outer wrapper click' function that I attached?

Can you share some resources online where I can read about this? I googled a lot and couldn't find a thig.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass down a callback through props.

Try the following:

```
function App() {
    const onClick = () => { console.log('outer wrapper click') }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Wrapper onClick={onClick}>
                <button>click me</button>
            </Wrapper>
        </div>
    );
}

function Wrapper ({onClick}) { // destructure props
    return (
        <div onClick={() => { onClick() }}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

In this way clicking on the `div` element the `onClick` callback from `App` component will be called.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sure, this helps! However, IDK if this is a common pattern to pass along props like this? This looks weird... wouldn't it be better to attach events on the <Wrapper onClick ... > instance?

Comment: @paroxyzm I think this is totally common usage of passing down through props a callback.